# Java won't accept Unicode characters as user input

Tags: java, unicode

I'm making an encryption software, and so far everything is great. You enter your message and my software selects 26 unicode characters in order from a random spot in the unicode table and switches each letter with its cooresponding unicode character. The problem is, however, that when I paste the encoded message (unicode characters) into the console, Java spits back different characters each time.

The following code yields this as a result:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String msg = sc.next();
System.out.println(msg);
```

> ⶫⶭ (entered to equal msg)
>
> â¶«â¶­ (given back by Java in the print statement)

Comment: You are supposed to tell the Scanner what character set the characters are in.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between Unicode (the abstract concept) and its _multibyte encodings_, including UTF-16 and  UTF-8, and other single-byte character encodings such as Windows-1252 and Latin-1.  This is much too large a topic to be re-described here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the encoding type that the `Scanner` should be reading in with

```
String encoding = "the encoding"; // e.g. UTF-8 etc.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, encoding);
```

This should fix your issue. Also, please note that when I tested your code as it was in the question on my machine, it worked properly and displayed ⶫⶭ from the print statement.

Comment: For `encoding` see: [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)